# How does Azure AD and Aspnet Core Identity work together?

Tags: c#, api, vue.js, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm currently setting up a project with Vue.Js as my front-end and Aspnet Core as my back-end. I've worked with both of the technologies before but I've never used Azure AD before. My Vue.js app can get access token from Azure AD and I've attached it as a bearer token but what I don't quite get is how do I use that token to then create a user in my database(EF Core) mapped to Identity? Assuming that I have a model that requires a userId

```
public class Post
{
     public string UserId {get; set;}
     //Other fields
}
```

I know that token contains claims and I can use that claim to identify users but since my database is empty how does that work?

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
            });
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
        // Some other stuff
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

appsettings.json looks like this

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "<something>.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "<something>",
  "ClientId": "<something>",
  "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"
},
```

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score -1):

To fulfill this scenario there are two parts to it:

1. Web App calls Web API on behalf of signed in user. To implement this, you will have to [Configure Client Application to call Web API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api) Following this, will help you to provide you Web app Delegated permissions for your Web API.
2. You don't have to necessarily check SQL db for users, you can Azure AD will do this internally for you, you just have to use below code:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // Adds Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0) support to protect this API
       services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");

       services.AddControllers();
   }
   ```

   For more details on Code configuration, visit [Protected web API: Code configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration).
3. **ASP.NET Core Identity:**

   - Is an API that supports user interface (UI) login functionality.
   - Manages users, passwords, profile data, roles, claims, tokens, email confirmation, and more.

   **Microsoft identity platform is:**

   - An evolution of the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) developer platform.
   - Unrelated to ASP.NET Core Identity.

   **ASP.NET Core Identity adds user interface (UI) login functionality to ASP.NET Core web apps. To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the following:**

   - Azure Active Directory
   - Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
   - IdentityServer4

   For different code setups, visit this: [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&amp%3Btabs=visual-studio&tabs=visual-studio)

*You have probably mixed two different approaches, pls have a look at these links for further clarification.*

Comment: "You don't have to necessarily check SQL db for users" but I do need to check my db for info related to the user. That info is not and can't be in the bearer token. Is there a way to mantain witch user from AD relates to my user db?